# Limit the file upload size in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

I am trying to limit the size of the upload image size  using the following code:

```
<input type="file"  class="upload" name="image"  value="<?php echo set_value('image'); ?>" /> <!--<button id='submit_btn' class="btn btn-default">upload</button> -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>               
                      <script type="text/javascript">
                       $(document).on('change','.upload',function(){
      files = this.files;
      size = files[0].size;
      //max size 50kb => 50*1000
      if( size > 1000141){
         alert('Please upload less than 1mb file');
         return false;
      }
      return true;
});
</script>
```

when i  upload the  image greater than 1 mb, upload goes through successfully. whats the issue  ? Bt the image  is not  uploaded in to the folder bt in to the database

Comment: thanks for ur reply   ..  can u explain it?

Comment: you can use Codeigniter file upload class

Comment: When i upload the file using Ci ,  upload goes through successfully,,  alert is  not display in this case  Please proviide solution for this issue

Comment: have you check `size` variable?What value it print in `console.log(size);`

Comment: Try this for file upload validation.. http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2014/07/javascript-to-validate-file-size-before.html.

Comment: The above mentioned code works correctly , 1048576 is the actual value which has to mentioned in if( size > 1048576 ) for 1mb. Can you please share your complete code to triage why it gets into database.?

Comment: The problem is that when i submit the form  validation is not working .How to validate onsubmit using jquery  for limit the  size of the upload image?

Answer (score 0):

File size Validation using jquery   (onsubmit  validation)  Try  this code , you will get the  result.

```
<form action="<?=site_url('search/do_register')?>"  method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return function();">
<input type="file"  class="upload" name="image"  value="<?php echo set_value('image'); ?>"/> 
<input type="submit" name="btn-reg" value="  Register   " />

                  <script type="text/javascript">
                       $(document).on('change','.upload',function(){
      files = this.files;
      size = files[0].size;
      //max size 50kb => 50*1000

      if( size > 1000141){
         alert('Please upload less than 1mb file');
         return false;
      }
      return true;
});
</script>
```